# firebase emulator data not saved and retrieved from some cache

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Getting data from firestore emulator works fine, manually added documents.

```
export const getMaterials = async (companyID: string): Promise<Material[]> => {
   const materials = await getDocs(collection(db, 
   `${COMPANIES}/${companyID}/materials`))
 return materials.docs.map<Material>((doc) => <Material>{ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
}
```

Saving also return with success but the data is not shown in the emulator UI but return from the above function the records from the emulator and the newly added records.

The data disappear after refreshing the app and the emulator.

```
 export const setMaterial = async (
  companyID: string,
  id: string
): Promise<any> => {
const docData = {
    companyID: companyID,
    id: id,
    name: name
  }
     const ret = await addDoc(collection(db, `${COMPANIES}/${companyID}/materials`), 
     docData)
     return ret
  }
```

Deleting documents from the emulator keep on returning from the getMaterial function. Again until restarting the app and the emulator.

Any idea where these guest documents is saved and why it's not saving to the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

related: [Firebase Firestore Emulator UI is not showing any data, but data is being returned in app query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67317018/firebase-firestore-emulator-ui-is-not-showing-any-data-but-data-is-being-return)

```
const config = {
  apiKey: 'AIz....3Jk1',
  projectId: 'local',
  authDomain: 'app.localhost.dev',
}
```

Changing projectId from local to the current project getting from the command

```
firebase projects:list
```

Solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue. Mine happened to be similar yet a bit different problem.

**THE ISSUE**

My app was part of **project-1** and Firestore part of **project-2**.

My dumb mistake was trying to initialize Firestore - `getFirestore()` - with configuration for **project-1** a connected it to emulator - `connectFirestoreEmulator`. That led to the same issues described by OP.

**TL;DR**

Check twice, if you are connecting to the right Firestore via `getFirestore()`.